# Specifying the Content-Type of each part of multipart/form-data in PHP's curl

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data

How do I specify the content type of a specific part of a multipart/form-data request? The content type for the image is being sent as `application/octet-stream`, however the server is expecting it to be `image/jpeg`. This causes the server to deny my request.

```
$data["file"] = "@/image.jpg";
$data["title"] = "The title";
$data["description"] = "The description";

//make the POST request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

This is the relevant parts of the request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------fc57f743c490

------------------------------fc57f743c490
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="NASA-23.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I want it to be:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------fc57f743c490

------------------------------fc57f743c490
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="NASA-23.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do something like this,

```
$data["file"] = "@/image.jpg;type=image/jpeg";

//make the POST request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: $header is not defined on the example. Is it a must?